# BuyNow button standard with HTML variables (RM=2) returns 0 value on old browsers

Tags: paypal

We use a BuyNow button standard with HTML variables (RM=2).

Sometimes, instead of receiving back the two variables, we get a 0 (zero) value. The customer pays, the payment is accepted, the customer and the merchant receive confirmation mails, but the system returns a zero value and the database can not be updated.

We discovered that this happens when the customer uses old browsers. For example Firefox 16.0.2 is one of the browsers that return a zero value.

Any idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue recently with Firefox, that when setting the rm=2 the data was getting returned as a GET instead of POST.  This may be what you are seeing, I believe there was a discussion on this on “Mozilla Support Forum”. Firefox automatically submits the data as “GET” method instead of “POST” method. This may be because of FF security properties.